# How to add numbers(integers) that are stored inside a string

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I have to create a program that uses Luhn's algorithm to check to see if a credit card is valid.

**The algorithm is this:**

Form a sum of every other digit, including the right-most digit; so 
5490123456789128 sums to 8+1+8+6+4+2+0+4 = 33
Form double each remaining digit, then sum all the digits that creates it; the remaining digits in our example (5 9 1 3 5 7 9 2) double to 10 18 2 6 10 14 18 4, which sums to 1+0+1+8+2+6+1+0+1+4+1+8+4 = 37
Add the two sums above (33+37 = 70)
If the result is a multiple of 10 (i.e., its last digit is 0) then it was a valid credit card number.

I made a Scanner and saved the credit card number into String card number
Then I created a while loop to save every other character starting from the right into a string. So now, I have a string filled with every other digit of the credit card number, starting from the right. However, I need to add up all of the digits within that string, which I can't figure out.

For example, if the user entered 1234 as the card number, the string everyotherdigit = 42. How can I add up 4 and 2 within the string?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code snippets of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hint: try using Character.digit.

Comment: Hint: the numeric value of any character  `c` in the range`'0'` through `'9'` can be calculated by `c - '0'`.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to do that. You can actually find your own solution by doing a bit of googling.

Anyway, this is what you can do:

- Get individual characters from your string, and convert them to int.

  ```
  String cardNumber = "5490123456789128";
  int value = cardNumber.charAt(0) - '0';
  ```

Using a for loop and changing `0` to `x`(loop counter) will solve everything.

- Get single String and convert to int.

  ```
  String cardNumber = "5490123456789128";
  int value = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(0,1));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

So something like this would work for you:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String cardNum = "5490123456789128";
    String others = null;
    int evenDigitSum = 0;
    int oddDigitTransformSum = 0;

    for (int pos = 0; pos < cardNum.length(); pos++)
    {
        if ((pos%2) != 0)
        {
            evenDigitSum +=  (cardNum.charAt(pos) - '0');
        }
        else
        {
            others = Integer.toString((cardNum.charAt(pos)-'0')*2);

            for (char c : others.toCharArray())
            {
                oddDigitTransformSum += (c-'0');
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Odds: " + oddDigitTransformSum);
    System.out.println("Evens: " + evenDigitSum);
    System.out.println("Total: " + (evenDigitSum+oddDigitTransformSum));
    System.out.println("Valid Card: " + ((evenDigitSum+oddDigitTransformSum)%10==0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd treat the string as an array of `char`s, and use [`Character.digit(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit(char,%20int)) to convert each character to the corresponsing `int`:

```
public static boolean isValidCreditCard (String s);
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();

    int everyOtherSum = 0;
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
        everyOtherSum += Character.digit(arr[i], 10);
    }

    int doubleSum = 0;
    for (for (int i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
        int currDigit = Character.digit(arr[i], 10);
        int doubleDigit = currDigit * 2;
        while (doubleDigit > 0) {
            doubleSum += (doubleDigit % 10);
            doubleDigit /= 10;
        }
    }

    int total = everyOtherSum + doubleSum;
    return total % 10 == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int cardCount(String numbers){
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    int count = 0;
    for(char c : numbers.toCharArray()){
        stack.push(Character.getNumericValue(c));
    }
    int size = stack.size();
    for(int i=1;i <= size; i++){
        if(i%2 != 0){
            count = count + stack.pop();
        }else{
            stack.pop();
        }

    }
    return count;
}
```

This just does what you asked, not the entire algorithm